# MongoDb UpdateOneAsync ExpressionFunction returning input string was not in a correct format

Tags: mongodb, generics, async-await, expression

I have a method it's signature like that

```
Task<bool> UpdateOneAsync<TDocument, TField>(TDocument documentToModify, Expression<Func<TDocument, TField>> field, TField value)
    where TDocument : IDocument;
```

and the method like that

```
public virtual async Task<bool> UpdateOneAsync<TDocument, TField>(TDocument documentToModify, Expression<Func<TDocument, TField>> field, TField value)
    where TDocument : IDocument
{
    var filter = Builders<TDocument>.Filter.Eq("Id", documentToModify.Id);
    var updateRes = await HandlePartitioned(documentToModify).UpdateOneAsync(filter, Builders<TDocument>.Update.Set(field, value));
    return updateRes.ModifiedCount == 1;
}
```

UpdateOneAsync signature like that in mongo:

```
Task<UpdateResult> UpdateOneAsync(FilterDefinition<TDocument> filter, UpdateDefinition<TDocument> update, UpdateOptions options = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
```

when i use this function from my layer like below it has throwing an exception

```
await _mongoDbRepository.UpdateOneAsync<XPartitionedDocument,float>(
                        documentToModify: isExist,
                        field: x => (float)x.TotalPrice,
                        value: td.TotalPrice
                        );
```

> "input string was not in a correct format"

The field TotalPrice is a number field in mongodb and is a (float or decimal) variable in class. What is meaning of this error and how should i use it?

Answer (score 0):

ok i got it done
I find out in mongo feature dlls has some new features and one of them not in MongoDb.Driver current C# version 2.7.3 instade of that together of this dll i have added MongoDb.Driver.Core.Signed 2.7.2 and MongoDb.Driver.Signed 2.7.2
problem has disapeared